# apache return 403 after adding ' " '

Tags: apache-http-server

After I try to access some URL's in my school website I found that when I try to add `"` at the end of the URL it get's me a `403 Forbidden`. Why is that?

Example:

`http://website.com/content/` Completly normal and return a webpage.

`http://website.com/content/"` gives me `403 Forbidden`.

Comment: There isn't a page named `"`. You might want to read [HTTP Error 403 Forbidden](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E403.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill Shouldn't it return "Page not found" or something like that?

Comment: "The Web server (running the Web site) thinks that the HTTP data stream sent by the client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) was correct, but access to the resource identified by the URL is forbidden for some reason.

This indicates a fundamental access problem, which may be difficult to resolve because the HTTP protocol allows the Web server to give this response without providing any reason at all. So the 403 error is equivalent to a blanket 'NO' by the Web server - with no further discussion allowed."